# GMap.NET Satellitemap providers error

Tags: vb.net, gmap.net

I'm using GMap.NET in winforms application But when i use Googlesatellite map provider it gives an error ,**Exception :The remote Server returned in error:(404) Not found**,
Other map providers works fine just problem with "GoogleSatelliteMapProvider",

Heres my code

```
With gmaps
        .Position = New PointLatLng(22.63, 71.58)
        .MinZoom = 3
        .MaxZoom = 17
        .Zoom = 8
        .Manager.Mode = AccessMode.ServerAndCache
        .CanDragMap = True
        GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleSatelliteMapProvider.Instance.APIKey = "MyApiKey"
        .MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleMapProvider.Instance
        .DragButton = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left
        .MouseWheelZoomType = GMap.NET.MouseWheelZoomType.MousePositionAndCenter
End With
```

Comment: I checked everything firewall antivirus and i'm not using proxy so whats the problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps You are using old version try new version . . . Go here and get new version [Greatmap Release](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/releases/view/73162)

Comment: Ohh yeah buddy i forgot that . . . .